# bar chart not showing geting Error: "category" is not a registered scale

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to show bar chart in the reactjs. i also downloaded dependecies of bar chart **chart.js** and **react-chartjs-2**

```
   "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

but bar chart not showing content and  I'm still getting the error

**Reactjs**

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
const BarComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Bar
        width={600}
        height={400}
        data={{
          labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "months",
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: "red",
            },
          ],
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default BarComponent;
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: ***I'm still getting the error*** what error?

Answer (score 12):

You've missed the register part, try adding this.

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
```

and then register it outside your component

```
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
```

you can refer to the example in there documentation
[here](https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/examples/vertical-bar-chart)